# Can't see the where "expected an indented block" should be

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know it's an indent issue but I can't see the indent problem with this. I've added added and removed indents, moved it all over, moved it all back... I've got square eyes on this one.

```
File "<ipython-input-20-f488c0f7671f>", line 7
    def __init__(self, start_time, time_limit=60):

IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Listener class:

```
class listener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, start_time, time_limit=60):
        self.time = start_time
        self.limit = time_limit
        self.tweet_data = []

    def on_data(self, data):
        saveFile = io.open('raw_tweets.json', 'a', encoding='utf-8')

        while (time.time() - self.time) < self.limit:
            try:
                self.tweet_data.append(data)
                return True
            except BaseException, e:
                print 'failed ondata,', str(e)
                time.sleep(5)
                pass

        saveFile = io.open('raw_tweets.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
        saveFile.write(u'[\n')
        saveFile.write(','.join(self.tweet_data))
        saveFile.write(u'\n]')
        saveFile.close()
        exit()

    def on_error(self, status):
        print statuses
```

Comment: As shown here, there is no problem. You probably want to use a better editor that actually shows what's going on. tabs vs spaces comes to mind.

Comment: This is almost certainly caused by mixing tabs & spaces. Tell your editor to make tabs visible.

Comment: Try using `python -t your_script.py` The -t on the command line should issue a warning if you are mixing tabs and spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be mixing tabs and spaces for indentation.

Check this:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces

> A text editor which automatically formats code will guide your code
>   from getting into such issues. [eg -Sublime Text editor (where you can make the following change: View -> Indentation -> Convert Indentation to Spaces) with Python
>   Flake8 Lint]

Comment: The link was very useful and will help me solve this problem.